# How to handle Ajax in selenium webdriver by using java script

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a code to test the webapplication but in my application We have AJAX Request the data will come by back end component.So it is taking some time to get data.

So can you please suggest me what is best method to use.

Advance Thanks
Raju

Answer (score 0):

Set an implicit timeout on the driver

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

When an element is not immediatly found, it will wait for it during 10 seconds before throwing an exception. That should give your ajax calls enough time to call back.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
@Override
public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
    return d.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
}});
```

This will wait for that particular element(myDynamicElement) in your page which is loaded through ajax.